# Update password in database mongodb, mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this route

`router.patch("/me/update-password", authenticate, (req, res) =>{

    let newPassword = _.pick(req.body, 'password');
    const newP = newPassword.password;

       User.findByCredentials(req.user.username, req.user.password).then((user) => {  
        user.password = newP;
        user.save().then(() => {
    res.send(user);
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  });
  });
});

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    UserSchema.statics.findByCredentials = function (username, password) {
  var User = this;

  return User.findOne({username}).then((user) => {
    if (!user) {
      return Promise.reject();
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Use bcrypt.compare to compare password and user.password
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
        if (res) {
          resolve(user);
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  let user = this;

  if (user.isModified('password')) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        user.password = hash;
        next();
      });
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});`

I find the username and password of the authenticated user and then I want to send a new password which I save as newP.

I want to update the password hash and salt it and then save, so I tried with the method user.save() which hashes and salts the password. But when I send a patch request it wont`t finish.
Does anybody know why ?

I tried everything but I am stuck.

Comment: Can you add some console.logs and see on which promise it hangs? I assume you are simply missing some `return` out there